# How to display the value of a key when user enters the key in textField in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield, uilabel

I'm trying to create a dictionary-like app using a `dictionary` with multiple `key`-`value` pairs.
The idea is when the user types and existing `key` in the `textField` and clicks the `button` the `value` of that `key` is displayed on the `label`. I could only get to display all the entries (including keys and values) when `button` is clicked (irrespective of the content of the `textField`), but that's not what I'm trying to achieve.

Here's my code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Dictionary
//
//  Created by Ralph on 7/20/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Ralph. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let words = [
        “doe” : “a deer, a female deer”,
        “ray" : “a drop of golden sun”,
        “me” : “a name I call myself”
    ]

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!        

    @IBAction func searchButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        displayMeaning.text = words.description
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var displayMeaning: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't see you are retrieving the value for the key entered in text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the text in the textfield like so

```
displayMeaning.text = words[textField.text]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Neil Horton, this short line of code solved my problem and behaved exactly as I wanted. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your `@IBAction` you should try this:

```
@IBAction func searchButton(sender: UIButton) {
    displayMeaning.text = words.objectForKey(textField.text)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @pbush25 for your assistamce. However, when I implemented your suggestion I got an error: '[String : String]' does not have a member named 'objectForKey'. So this didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Sorry @Mandroid it probably should have been `words.valueForKey(textField.text)`

Comment: It's okay, you're just trying to help ;-)  Still getting an error though. But not to worry, the problem's solved. I appreciate your time and help.